# VS2012 constantly breaking on JavaScript exceptions

Tags: javascript, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am working in a VB.NET solution. Each time I try debugging the the solution, I get bombarded with pop-ups from Visual Studio 2012 about various JavaScript exceptions. Here is a [screencast](http://screencast.com/t/8RYE0SQo) showing the problem.

After clicking continue for 20 times or so, the solution would load fine in the browser and everything works OK. Until I of course navigate to some other link and then I get all them pop-ups again.

What is causing this? How can I stop this from happening? PS. I have told VS2012 not to stop for JavaScript exceptions, but it still happens.

[image: js exceptions]

Comment: i guess you are using IE, it happens to me too, but i'm used to use Chrome

Comment: At work I have to use IE :( It is what our programs must work on. Otherwise I use Chrome.

Comment: Actually one of my coworkers likes more IE because he gets the error so you will not miss any of them. Anyway you could try to stop the "Debug" session and then just test the JS, this should work.